# How we can modify Activity creation wizard of Android studio to add additional attribute

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, live-templates

From Right click in project explorer --> new option in Android Studio allow us to create Activity, Fragment etc which create file/files for us using predefined template. In Activity creation wizard makes entry in Manifest file with name attribute. my question is how we can modify this wizard to add additional attribute in manifest file entry of activity like orientation,theme.

the auto generated code in manifest file should look like this

```
            <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MyNewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreen" />
```

I tried file template and live template in Android studio but couldn’t find the way to insert additional attribute in manifest file.